# How to split the dataset in a stratified way (Matlab)?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, dataset

I have a 30x500 data matrix and a 3x500 target matrix. This is a classification problem. I need to divide the data into training, validation and testing (80%, 10%, 10%), but I want to maintain the proportion of each class in the divided data. How can I do this in Matlab?

---

Edit:
The target matrix contains the labels (one hot) of the correct class (there are three classes)

```
|0 0 1 ... 1|
|1 0 0 ... 0|
|0 1 0 ... 0|3x500
```

The data matrix contains 500 samples with 30 predictor variables (30x500).

```
|2 0 1 4 8 1 ... 2|
|4 1 5 8 7 3 ... 0|
|1 3 6 4 2 1 ... 6|
|. . . . . . . . .|
|3 5 8 4 0 0. .. 1| 30x500
```

Comment: Can you describe what are you calling a class? What does the target matrix contain exactly?

Comment: I edited the question and put that information.
The target matrix is ​​a one hot matrix, with zeros and ones. There are three possible classes of data.

Comment: But do you want the data to maintain proportion in esperance over multiple random splitting? Or do you want to enforce the respet of proportion for every split?

Comment: I donwvoted because images of text.

Comment: @bousof I want to keep the same proportion and random selection of the data.

Comment: Thanks for correcting your question. I upvoted to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage to inmpose the number of each class by computing the percentiles associated to the cumulative probabilities, and then associate each interval to the associated interval. Let's use this strategy to first create a random dataset containing exactly 50% of class 1, 30% of class 2, and 20% of class 3 (not that you don't have to do that in your case as you already have the class matrix `classmat` and data matrix `datamat`):

```
clc; clear all; close all;

% Parameters
c = 3; % number of classes
d = 500; % number of data
o = 30; % number of data for each observation
propd = [0.4, 0.2, 0.4]; % proportions of each class in the original data (size 1xc)

% Generation of fake data
datamat = randi([0,15],o,d); % test data matrix
propd_os = cumsum([0, propd]); propd_os(end) = 1;
randmat = rand(d,1);
classmat = zeros(c,d); % test class matrix
for i=1:c
    prctld = prctile(randmat, 100*propd_os); prctld(1) = 0; prctld(end) = 1;
    classmat(i,randmat>=prctld(i) & randmat<prctld(i+1)) = 1;
end

% Proportions of the original data
disp(['original data proportions:' sprintf(' %.3f',sum(classmat,2)/d)])
```

When executed, this code creates the `classmat` matrix and displays the proportions of each class in this matrix:

```
>>>
original data proportions: 0.400 0.200 0.400
```

I created for you a script to split this dataset into parts that respects the same proportions of the original dataset:

```
%% Splitting parameters
s = 3; % number of parts
props = [0.8, 0.1, 0.1]; % proportions of each splitted datasets (size 1xs)
props_os = cumsum([0, props]); props_os(end) = 1;
randmat = rand(1,d);
splitmat = zeros(s,d); % split matrix (one hot)
for i=1:c
    indc = classmat(i,:)==1;
    prctls = prctile(randmat(indc), 100*props_os); prctls(1) = 0; prctls(end) = 1;
    for j=1:s
        inds = randmat>=prctls(j) & randmat<prctls(j+1);
        splitmat(j,indc&inds) = 1;
    end
end

% Proportions of classes in each split parts
disp(['original split proportions:' sprintf(' %.3f',sum(splitmat,2)/d)])
for j=1:s
    inds = splitmat(j,:)==1;
    disp([sprintf('part %d proportions:', j) sprintf(' %.3f',sum(classmat(:,inds),2)/sum(inds))])
end
```

You obtain with this 3 parts containing 80%, 10% and 10%. Each of these have the same proportion of each class than the original dataset:

```
>>>
original split proportions: 0.800 0.100 0.100
part 1 proportions: 0.400 0.200 0.400
part 2 proportions: 0.400 0.200 0.400
part 3 proportions: 0.400 0.200 0.400
```

Note that you cannot always obtain the exact proportions beacause it depends on the size of the datasets and their divisibility by the inverses of the proportions... But I think it should do what you want. Please do not hesitate to ask question if you have troubles with the code. At the end you obtain a one hot `splitmat` matrix. `splitmat(s,d)` equals `1` if datapoint `d` belongs to part `s`.